# Translate the following MIPS instructions into 32 bit instructions

Tags: assembly, mips, machine-code, addressing

I'm trying to translate the following MIPS instructions into 32 bit machine code (using Big-endian):

`swc1 $f1 8($t0)`

What I did was:

```
111001 00001 01000 00001000
```

I'm only sure about the translation of swc1, but not the others. I've googled a lot but couldn't find the number of $f1. I also read this thread:
[Link to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902712/what-number-registers-are-the-floating-point-registers-in-mips) However I'm still not sure if I should use 00001 for $f1. As for the machine code of offset 8 and $t0, am I doing it right?

Comment: Big-endian or little-endian?

Comment: It's Big-endian since it's in MIPS I think. Correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you!

Comment: MIPS can be either. Also, AFAIK, MIPS instruction-endianness does not have to be the same as data-endianness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since instructions are 32 bit, the machine code format has space for a 16 bit immediate, as follows:

`111001 Rs[5] Ft[5] Offs[16]`

(The numbers in brackets indicate bit counts.)

Note that `$t0` is register #8, and `$f1` is indeed register #1. As such your instruction is:

```
111001 01000 00001 0000000000001000
= 1110 0101 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 1000 = E5 01 00 08
```

You can of course verify it using a trusted assembler:

```
1 0000 E5010008      swc1 $f1, 8($t0)
```